# How would I bind keypresses for an app?

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

mithril talks plenty about binding and eventing if they are simple variable changes, but what about binding say the `+` key to functionality? I tried `m.withAttr('keyCode')` binding to the controller method that I wanted to handle it, but nothing.

[Sample Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/V2dfMw?p=preview)

Comment: You might try asking on the [Mithril mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mithriljs).

Comment: The first answer perfectly answers it. You can bind a `callback` to a key, basically.

Answer (score 7):

Mithril doesn't have a helper for properties that aren't attributes of the DOM element. `withAttr` only deals with DOM element attributes (as the name implies). For keyCode, you need to define a custom helper

```
function withKey(key, callback) {
  return function(e) {
    var ch = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
    if (ch == key) callback(key)
    else m.redraw.strategy("none") //don't redraw (v0.1.20+ only)
  }
}

m("div", {onkeypress: withKey("+", ctrl.doSomething)})
```

The else statement is just there to prevent a redraw if the pressed key is not the one you're looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to set the redraw strategy again at some later time to turn auto-redrawing back on? (I'm really liking Mithril, BTW).

Comment: No, m.redraw.strategy only applies to the next scheduled redraw

Comment: Ahh. Good to know; I don't believe the documentation makes that clear anywhere - I don't recall reading that (though I may have missed it).

Comment: Currently it's a bit skimpy, yes. Better docs will be released in 0.1.22

Answer (score 4):

Mithril doesn't handle the entire page and it's events for you. You could `addEventListener` for `window.onkeydown` and within that callback do what you need, such as update the controller or redraw the page.

http://jsbin.com/hikinoza/1/edit

---

The `m.prop` or `m.withAttr` by themselves are not binding anything anywhere. The real binding happens when you specify some `onXXX` property for an object such as

```
m('div', {onClick: myFunc})
```

This will attach a real `onClick` event to the real `div` dom node that will be created.

Answer (score 3):

The Mithril rendering fcn `m(tag, attrs, children)` allows you to specify the special property `config` in `attrs`. It allows you to call methods on the DOM element after it gets created. See the section called [Accessing the real DOM element](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.html).

You can easily abuse Mithril with this, but its a proper use for attaching non-standard event handlers. Something like the following should work:

```
m('li', {config: setupKeyHandler}, 'foo');

function setupKeyHandler (el, isInitialized, context) {
  el.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {})
}
```